# Can you read ARMv7-M machinecode backwards?

Tags: arm, disassembly

or alternatively when picking a random half-word can you tell the difference if it is a thumb (16bit) or an arm (32bit) instruction?

Background: when using a monitor program (in the good ol' days) you could type something like `d $c000` to show a disassembly of the machine code starting with that address. Then you could scroll down or *up* to show more lines.

But then the disassembler whould have to know where a command starts. This is easy for fixed width instructions. I wonder how / if this is done for variable width (or fixed but with different width) instructions.

Comment: no you cant, you have to disassemble in execution order and further have to emulate.  the same problem as on x86 or 6502 or any other variable length instruction set.  arm/thumb is the same/worse.

Comment: That's what I supposed. (I really like the 32 bit arm code from pre thumb area...) Do you have any idea how this is done e.g. by the c64/6510 monitor programs like in final cartridge / action replay where you can scroll upward? Backtracking until illegal opcodes?